# How to detect end of a document

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a java ee application where I'm using JSF with Primefaces.

Now I need to open a dialog where PDF document is displayed.It is disabled to print or download the document. So I have hidden the bar.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="dlgpdf" height="800" width="950" header="pdf" maximizable="false" minimizable="false" resizable="false" dynamic="true" showEffect="clip">
     <p:media value="#{DIPCSS.downloadFiles()}" player="pdf" width="900px" height="600px" id="pdfvisualizer">
         <f:param name="idee" value="#{DIViewBean.id}" />
         <f:param name="#toolbar" value="0" />
    </p:media>
</p:dialog>
```

Everything is fine here.

**But how do I know that the user has scrolled to the end of the document?** Then I want to enable the button press.

I've tried a lot of JS code, but none of it works for me. The problem is probably that it's in a dialog and there is a new html structure. Any recommendations?

I try this now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     const myDiv = document.getElementById('pdfvisualizer')
     myDiv.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
           if (myDiv.offsetHeight + myDiv.scrollTop >= myDiv.scrollHeight) { console.log('scrolled to bottom')}
              })
</script>
```

And Error is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: The PDF file is directly displayed on the page. It is displayed using primefaces media. And I want to react to it if it goes through the whole pdf. It doesn't matter how fast, but whether it reaches the end.

Comment: It is on the web page of my java ee application.

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/media.xhtml?jfwid=e32e5 Something like this.

Comment: Ok, so there's just an option in the dialog to show the full preview of the pdf and a button to put under.